# Length of parametric curve

Tags: definite-integrals, parametrization

Se have parametric curve with the formula for $x(t)$ and $y(t)$: $$x(t) = \int^{t}_{0} \sqrt{2cos(u) - 1}du$$ and $$ y(t)= \int^{t}_{0} \sqrt{2cos(u) + 5}du$$.
I have to find the largest interval $[0, t_{0}]$, on which is this parametric curve defined and then I have to find also lenght of that curve.
So how do I start this exercise, because first I tried to find the undefine integral of $x(t)$ and $y(t)$ but I could not find them.

Any help?

Comment: Since $|\cos(u)|\leq 1$, $y(t)$ is always well defined. However, $x(t)$ is only well defined for $|\cos(t)|\leq \frac{1}{2}$. From there, proceed using $t_0 = \arccos(\frac{1}{2}) = \frac{\pi}{3}$.

Answer (score 2):

The integrand in $y(t)$ is always defined ($2\cos u+5\ge3$), but the expression under the square root in $x(t)$ becomes zero at $\cos u=\frac12$ or $u=\pi/3$, going upwards from $0$. Thus $t_0=\pi/3$ and the length of the curve is
$$\int_0^{\pi/3}\sqrt{x'(t)^2+y'(t)^2}\,dt=\int_0^{\pi/3}\sqrt{(\sqrt{2\cos t-1})^2+(\sqrt{2\cos t+5})^2}\,dt$$
$$=\int_0^{\pi/3}\sqrt{4\cos t+4}\,dt=\int_0^{\pi/3}\sqrt{8\cos^2\frac t2}\,dt$$
$$=2\sqrt2\int_0^{\pi/3}\cos\frac t2\,dt=2\sqrt2\left[2\sin\frac t2\right]_0^{\pi/3}$$
$$=2\sqrt2\cdot2\sin\frac\pi6=2\sqrt2$$